# How to install a house number plaque on vinyl siding?

Tags: exterior, siding, vinyl-siding, sheathing

I need to install house numbers on my house. I have obtained an aluminium plaque with the numbers and I'm now wondering the best way to install it onto the house.

The house has vinyl siding, and underneath the siding is [ZIP system](http://www.huberwood.com/zipsystem/home-zip-system) sheathing.

From some googling around, it would seem that I have two options:

- Drill screws through the siding, into the sheathing, to secure the plaque.
- Obtain some sort of vinyl siding hook, and use it to hang the plaque on top of the siding.

Which of these approaches would be best to take? My concern with screw approach is, of course, the fact that moisture may be able to get behind the siding. The ZIP system serving as a moisture barrier may additionally complicate this; I'm not sure.

The siding hook seems like a nice and simple approach, but I don't know how permanent the installation will be and if it is difficult to find hooks compatible with siding.

The plaque comes with screws and is clearly intended to be screwed in, as described in the instructions. I would just follow the directions exactly but they do not mention vinyl siding or dealing with exposure to water, something that I've been warned to be concerned about.

[image: Instructions for Plaque Installation]

Comment: What sort of hanging mechanism does the plaque have on it?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the plaque hanging approach. I posted the original question before I saw the instructions but the question as to whether the exposure to water is of concern still stands.

Comment: If you live in a condo complex, you are forbidden from nailing, drilling, or screwing into vinyl siding. And for good reason, siding must be able to move which is why the nail holes are all slotted so they can. Failure to move in the heat of summer causes what is called "oil canning". The siding buckles like crazy. Stick to the methods above where they use hooks that clip onto the siding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have hung a 4x8 ft trellis spaced 3" from the wall and supporting a large climbing rose on the side of my house through the vinyl siding. No leaks, and has been there for 6 years. Here's how:

Firstly, my vinyl siding is not flat. Each vinyl "board" has an upper section that is flat to the OSB sheathing of the house, and a lower protruding section that is spaced about ½" from the sheathing. Drill your holes to accommodate the screw through this upper, flush-to-the-sheathing portion of the siding, so that the sign will not compress the protruding portions of the vinyl siding.

Fashion a short "standoff" that will space the rear of your sign the same distance as the most protruding part of your siding. I cut short lengths from a plastic toilet infeed pipe for the tubular standoff, but you can probably figure a dozen ways to do this.

Put a dab of silicone or exterior caulk on the end of the standoff that will sit on the siding. Pass the screw through the sign and the standoff and fasten into the sheathing. Done!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use silicone, as you can you can just rub it off after it is done (I would expect a small bit of damage but nothing that destroys integrity).  You might need to tape it until the silicone is dry if the numbers are heavy.

Comment: I'd go this route as well except that the plaque is metal, and probably somewhat heavy. Add to that the likelihood of damage if it drops and I'd probably lean towards a mechanical fastener.

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of hooks designed for hanging objects from vinyl siding.  They are available in both metal and plastic.  I am currently using a plastic hook to hang a house number plaque over my garage. It has held up fine for almost 3 years now.  Just google vinyl siding hooks and you will find a wide selection. If your plaque is heavy, you can use 2 hooks. The one i am using is called VZ Hang 7 Pack Vinyl Siding Hook and is available from Amazon and directly from the manufacturer (cheaper than Amazon).