# Installing hose reel to vinyl siding

Tags: exterior, vinyl-siding

I bought the hose reel in the pictures below and I'm looking to install it on my exterior wall that has vinyl siding. I tried to do some research on the best way to attach hardware to vinyl siding and couldn't find much (or my Google skills aren't great, that's a likely possibility. Based on the limited info I was able to find I can think of two options:

**Option 1**

Of course, the reel didn't come with any instructions but given that this thing needs to hold a decent amount of weight and that the mounting holes are 16" apart I think I can safely assume I need to install it onto studs so:

1. Drilling some holes and attaching the reel directly against the siding
2. As mentioned [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93790/how-to-install-a-house-number-plaque-on-vinyl-siding) I could cut larger holes and use some kind of spacer/standoff (thin PVC pipe?) to keep the reel off the siding but attached to the house

Before I go drilling/cutting holes in my siding I wanted to see if either option is worth doing or if there's a better option to get this thing attached. Thanks!

**Pictures**
[image: Hose Reel Front]
[image: Hose Reel Back]
[image: Siding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't. **Put a post in the ground** and mount to that. Putting holes in maintenance-free siding should be a last resort.

Comment: This feels like a non-answer but I decided not to punch holes in the siding because it just seemed like I would be asking for trouble. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I agree, it doesn't answer your question. Call it a frame challenge.

Answer (score 1):

When I mounted exterior speakers to vinyl siding I inserted some thin wooden blocks underneath the siding. Get a [vinyl removal tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B8HGZPZN) to pop out the siding. Place your block underneath. This will give you a solid surface to screw into.